# Can Mixins interact with the class using it in DynamicProxy?

Tags: castle-dynamicproxy, mixins

Is using Interceptors the only way for a mixin to interact with the calling class other mixins?

I'm looking to do something like below.

### PsuedoCode

```
class speak
  void Greet()
  {  Console.WriteLine("Greetings! My Name is " + self.firstname); }

class person
  string firstname;

SpeakingPersonProxy = MixIn(person,speak);

SpeakingPersonProxy.firstname = "Noneya"
SpeakingPersonProxy.Greet()  //produces Greetings! My name is Noneya
```

self.firstname(or something like it) would somehow point to class using greet, instead of the speak class.  Ruby has a similar concept, which makes sense for a dynamic language.  Was wondering how to achieve this in DynamicProxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but what's stopping you from:

```
SpeakingPersonProxy = MixIn(person,speak);
speak.Person = person;
```

so in other words, if the `speak` hsa to know about its target, be explicit.